# Change the content with the url on php?

Tags: php, url

I have a file named friend.php and I want change the friend.php content doing this:

```
friend.php?content=1, friend.php?content=2
```

Searching on google I can find change elements from url but I want change the content complete for example have `content1.php`, `content2.php...` but show that only doing this with the url.

Comment: Just in case you're looking for the [`require()`](http://www.php.net/require) or [`include()`](http://www.php.net/include) methods. You can use these in conjunction with [esqew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52505719/247893) to load your appropriate content. If you want it to be more dynamic use `require(sprintf('content%d.php', $_GET['content']));` to automatically load `content<numberFromUrl>.php`.

Answer (score 2):

Access this using [`$_GET` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

```
<?php
  if ($_GET["content"] == "1") {
    // show content1.php
  } else if ($_GET["content"] == "2") {
    // show content2.php
  }
?>
```